# How can I force single threaded behavior in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, concurrency, callback, casperjs

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm just learning to work with its concurrency model. Right now, I have the following code in which I'm trying to implement a busyWait function:

```
function captureFile() {
  return "screenshots/anthem" + ++numCaptures + ".png"
};

function busyWait(casper, selector, action) {
  casper.echo('busyWait', 'INFO');
  casper.waitUntilVisible(
    selector,
    function then() {
      this.capture(captureFile());
      casper.captureSelector(captureFile(), selector);
      casper.echo(selector + ' is Visible', 'INFO');
      action(casper);
    },
    function onTimeout() {
      casper.capture(captureFile());
      casper.echo('Continue to Wait', 'INFO');
      busyWait(casper, selector);
    },
    1000
  );
};

casper.start(anthem_url, function () {
  // Try to find the survey and dismiss it.
  var surveyID = 'div.fsrFloatingContainer';
  busyWait(this, surveyID, function action(casper) {
    casper.clickLabel('No, thanks', 'a');
    casper.echo('Dismissed Survey', 'INFO');
  });

  // enter Last Name
  var nameID = '#ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_SearchWizard6_LastName';
  busyWait(this, nameID, function action(casper) {
    casper.sendKeys(nameID, name);
    casper.echo('Set Name to: ' + name, 'INFO');
  });
  this.sendKeys(nameID, name);
  this.capture(captureFile());
});

casper.run(function () {
  this.exit();
});
```

Running code above returns:

```
$casperjs casper_anthem.js
busyWait
busyWait
div.fsrFloatingContainer is Visible
Dismissed Survey
#ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_SearchWizard6_LastName is Visible
Set Name to: Smith
```

So, the problem is that I'm using callbacks to implement a busyWait loop. Of course this doesn't work because callbacks are asynchronous in JavaScript. My question is: how can I force a synchronous behavior from my callbacks?

**Solution**

Turns out the `then()` function in CasperJS is actually the way to do this.

```
function busyWait(casper, selector, action) {
  casper.waitUntilVisible(
    selector,
    function then() {
      casper.echo(selector + ' is Visible', 'INFO');
      casper.captureSelector(captureFile(), selector);
      action(casper);
      casper.capture(captureFile());
    },
    function onTimeout() {
      casper.echo('Continue to Wait for ' + selector, 'INFO');
      casper.capture(captureFile());
      busyWait(casper, selector, function action(casper) { action(casper) });
    },
    5000
  );
};

casper.start(anthem_url);

// Try to find the survey and dismiss it.
casper.then(function () {
  this.capture(captureFile());
  busyWait(this, surveyID, function action(casper) {
    casper.clickLabel('No, thanks', 'a');
    casper.echo('Dismissed Survey', 'INFO');
  });
});

// enter Last Name
casper.then(function () {
  var nameID = '#ctl00_MainContent_maincontent_SearchWizard6_LastName';
  this.waitWhileSelector(surveyID, function () {
    busyWait(this, nameID, function action(casper) {
      casper.sendKeys(nameID, name);
      casper.echo('Set Name to: ' + name, 'INFO');
    });
  });
});

casper.run();
```

Basically, I just need to put each action in its own `then()` block and let CasperJS manage serializing them.

Comment: You don't. You construct your logic with the asynchronous behavior as part of the design.

Comment: Please remove the **Solution** from your question and post it as a separate answer. You can then accept it after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Pointy's got the answer.  Anything that happens once the container becomes visible has to be coded in the `then` function, which is going to execute after the main block of code is done.  If you are going to present the user with a series of inputs, with the nature of each input (such as text or button) dependent on results from previous inputs, you will end up with a lot of nested callbacks.  (That's how it's supposed to work.)

(In practice, you can make this look nicer by calling functions to do the work.  This saves on indenting, but it means someone looking at the code will take a while to figure out the real flow of the code.)

The tendency--until you get used to this--is to write sequential code:

```
first do this ...
then do this ...
then this ...
```

and that doesn't work in this sort of UI.

Comment: Valid point, but doesn't answer the question. I agree with you completely.